# Tile tilemapping render error

Tags: tilemap, rpg, tiles

I'm having rendering issues in Tiled with a border tile I'm applying to shapes.

In Tiled:

[image]

In game:

[image]

I'm using [Tile Flipping](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/) to reduce work. I thought this may be the issue, so I tested out a few tiles by themselves:

Tiled:

[image]

In game: They render as expected

[image]

What may be the cause of this?

My game engine is [Melon JS](http://melonjs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possibly a bug in the renderer. Try with and without WebGL. Also file a ticket on the issue tracker, providing the library version and minimal example to reproduce: https://github.com/melonjs/melonJS/issues

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the rendering is off by 1 pixel (texel) for the flipped tiles or the source copy isn't flipped properly and catches most the next/previous tile in the tileset.

Comment: Exactly. The '1' shape is horizontally aligned with the tiles on the right in tiled, but not in game.